# Server Error When Programming PHP on Linux

Tags: php, apache, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

I'm programming php on fedora 16.When there is an error in my code and run it, I'll see Server Error and when I check /var/log/httpd/error_logs I see that internal error kis for my php error
. how can I see PHP errors in the browser like as xampp in windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the PHP INI configuration parameter display_errors to 1 (instead of the default of 0). Note that this is discouraged in a production environment. I assume you're only going to enable this on your development box.